# .htaccess How to redirect to index.html with params but the param value is same as a folder name

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

The routing url is like 'my_website/:param'

But my location contain a folder name is as same as the params.
So when I browse with http://my_website/apple.
The browser will display the folder instead of pass the value 'apple' to the web.

How should I set the .htaccess?Thanks
The following only work when the folder with same value is not exist.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your htaccess file in your question, could you please do let us know link `http://my_website/apple` should be served by which file(eg--> .php file etc) from backend?

Comment: my front end use React.js. so it will be serve by index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.html [L]
```

OR if you are looking only for link which starts with `apple` then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^apple index.html [NC,L]
```

***Problem in OP's tried code:*** `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]` will create an loop because there is no condition mentioned, so its going true each time for each uri.